# How to get Siri to dial my contact called "voicemail"?

Tags: iphone, contacts, siri

I have a contact in my iPhone called "voicemail" that dials my company voicemail service. If I ask Siri to "call voicemail" it just says "you have no new voicemails" as it's trying to check the mobile network's voicemail service (even though I've changed the voicemail shortcut in the Phone app to dial said contact).

I'm sure I've managed to get it to call the voicemail contact in the past by saying something like "call contact voicemail" but today that didn't work. Other than changing the name of the contact, what can I do to get Siri to dial this contact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know your question states: *Other than changing the name of the contact, what can I do to get Siri to dial this contact?*, but you don't clarify why you don't want to do it this way?

I'm not aware of another way to do this, and in my case changing the contact name works flawlessly. I just created a contact called "*Company Name* Voicemail" and Siri has no problems whatsoever.

I just say, "Hey Siri, call..." and *she* just dials the number and I go from there.

Comment: Call it OCD, call it stubbornness. It's mostly because I'm sure at one point I got Siri to call this contact, I just can't remember how (or Apple "fixed" it with an update).

Comment: Oh, well, I also had luck getting it to work without renaming the contact, but it became very frustrating because it was so hit and miss, especially while driving. After a couple of weeks I just decided I had better things to do with my time, so I just did it this way. Now it just works. :)

Comment: Doesn't even work if I change the contact to "company voicemail". It's just saying "you don't have any voicemail messages from company".

Comment: Oh, just added a sentence to the end of my answer with what I say to get it to work.

Comment: That's what I'm trying. No joy. Maybe it's because we're running different versions of iOS. I'm on the 10.3 beta.

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't have thought that would cause problems, but you never know. Another possibility may be the actual company name you're using? Can you abbreviate it (e.g. If you worked for General Motors, try _GM Voicemail_ for your contact).

Comment: " It's mostly because I'm sure at one point I got Siri to call this contact" As you surmise, Apple changes Siri all the time on their end—you don't even have to update your phone, since all the logic is server side. That would be my guess as to why it worked before.

Comment: “(Company name) voicemail is working again.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a nickname to the company voicemail contact.

- On the iPhone, go the Contacts app, select the contact, and tap 'Edit' (top-right).
- Scroll almost all the way to the bottom and tap 'Add Field'
- Tap 'Nickname'
- The 'Nickname' field will be added near the top of the contact entry (when I tested it, the field appeared under 'Last Name' and before 'Company').
- Try entering something like 'Office Voicemail' or whatever else you want to try.

Then try invoking Siri to say 'Call Office Voicemail' and see if it will use the Nickname.

I've had luck with this for other people, but I haven't tried it for voicemail, so I can't say for sure if it'll work.

Comment: Recent builds of iOS allow “(company) voicemail” to work again, so it’s not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

on iOS 12 create a shortcut (automation) - add to SIRI & add to Home screen & enable SIRI to do what you ask. 
You can check this link : https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/welcome/ios

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on how to do what you're suggesting. Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.